# Possible remainders of a perfect square when divided by $3,5,6$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A perfect square will have in its prime factorization all the primes having an even power, so that the square root will simply divide each by $2$.

Let the two constituents of a perfect square number ($p$) be : $mm$, i.e. same positive integer is repeated twice.
There can be two types of primes: odd, even, as say $p= 3^4.2^2, 2^4, 3^4$ .
(i) The even prime has the form of $2^{2k}=4^k$, for some positive integer $k$. 
(ii) The odd prime has the form of $(2n+1)^{2k}$, for some positive integer $k,n$.

Need find: 
(i) the remainders by congruence arithmetic approach for these two forms of perfect number constituents separately, & 
(ii)find product of these terms
under modulo $3,5,6$.

---

*Edit* Let us take the first few positive integers' squares $\gt1$, and based on each prime's residue class, will find their prime factorization.:
$2^2 => \equiv 1 \pmod 3, \equiv -1 \pmod 5, \equiv -2 \pmod 6$
$3^2 => \equiv 0 \pmod 3, \equiv -1 \pmod 5, \equiv 3 \pmod 6$

$4^2 = 2^4 => \equiv 1^2 \pmod 3, \equiv (-1)^2 \pmod 5, \equiv (-2)^2 \pmod 6 => \equiv 1 \pmod 3, \equiv 1 \pmod 5, \equiv 4 \pmod 6$

$5^2 => \equiv 1 \pmod 3, \equiv 0 \pmod 5, \equiv 1 \pmod 6$

$6^2=(2.3)^2=2^2.3^2 $
 $=> (\equiv 1 \pmod 3, \equiv -1 \pmod 5, \equiv -2 \pmod 6)\cdot(\equiv 0 \pmod 3, \equiv -1 \pmod 5, \equiv 3 \pmod 6)$
 $=> (\equiv (1.0) \pmod 3, \equiv (-1.-1) \pmod 5, \equiv (-2.3) \pmod 6)$
  $=> \equiv 0 \pmod 3, \equiv 1 \pmod 5, \equiv 0\pmod 6$

$7^2=> \equiv 1 \pmod 3, \equiv 3 \pmod 5, \equiv 1 \pmod 6$

$8^2=2^6 => (\equiv 1 \pmod 3, \equiv -1 \pmod 5, \equiv -2 \pmod 6)^3$
  $=> \equiv 1^3 \pmod 3, \equiv (-1)^3 \pmod 5, \equiv (-2)^3 \pmod 6$
=> $\equiv 1 \pmod 3, \equiv -1 \pmod 5, \equiv -2 \pmod 6$

$9^2=3^4 => (\equiv 0^2 \pmod 3, \equiv (-1)^2 \pmod 5, \equiv 3^2 \pmod 6)$
 $=>\equiv 0 \pmod 3, \equiv 1 \pmod 5, \equiv 3 \pmod 6$

Comment: This is not clear.  What are the "two constituents of a perfect square number"?  Please work some numerical examples to make your meaning clear.

Comment: @lulu I hope the edited post makes it clear, by examples of $3^4.2^2, 2^4, 3^4$. I meant that there can be two types of primes in the prime-factorization, and they are to have an even power each. In the even prime, there is only one prime, while in odd prime category, there are the rest

Comment: If I have guessed your question (which is still confusing) I think it's better to start from the squares rather than from the primes. Start by finding the remainders of the squares $1, 4, 9, 16, \dots$ modulo $3$. Do you see a pattern? Can you prove it continues? Then do the same for the other moduli you are interested in.

Comment: Not clear to me.  I suggested writing out some numerical examples of your full question.  Why not do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but it's possible you might be interested in the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity, if you are not already familiar with it.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity

Comment: Numerical examples are a vital tool in number theory.  Aside from clarifying questions, looking at examples sometimes reveals patterns (though sometimes they just show that the situation is more complex than you might have hoped).

Comment: @EthanBolker The pattern is $1, 0$ for numbers $\gt 1$ for modulo $3$. For modulo $5$, the pattern is : $1,-1, -1, 1,0$. For modulo $6$, the pattern is : $1,-2,3,4,1,0,1,-2$. Unable to grasp anything as pattern.

Comment: @lulu I have edited OP to show numerical example for prime constituents having even power.

Comment: Writing down $2^2, 3^2,\cdots$ isn't an example of anything.  Voting to close the question.

Comment: @lulu I am in the process of editing, please give me some more time before reconsidering it.

Comment: @lulu I have completed the edit. Please suggest more, if needed.

Comment: If all you want is the sequence of squares mod $3,5,6$ then, to take $5$ as an example, the sequence $\{1,4,9,16,25,\cdots, \}$ is periodic $\pmod 5$.  Specifically, it is $\overline { \{1,4,4,1,0\}}$.  Similar results hold for any modulus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is an odd prime $>3$, then

- $p\equiv \pm 1\mod 3$, so $p^2\equiv 1\mod 3$;
- $p\equiv \pm 1,\pm 2\mod 5$, so $p^2\equiv \pm 1\mod 5$;
- $p\equiv \pm 1\mod 6$, so $p^2\equiv 1\mod 6$.